# Correct format for hours between two times in java

Tags: java, datetime, netbeans, time, jodatime

I am trying to count the number of hours between two times in java.  I'm using the joda time library to format it.  The program can pull times entered in text boxes & put them in localTime variables:

```
LocalTime startTime1;
LocalTime airTime1;
LocalTime foamTime1;
LocalTime scTime1;
```

A start button then performs the following

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
startTime1 = formatter.parseLocalTime(startField2.getText());
airTime1 = formatter.parseLocalTime(airField.getText());
foamTime1 = formatter.parseLocalTime(fTimeField2.getText());
scTime1 = formatter.parseLocalTime(remainingField2.getText());
```

I then want to calculate the time between airTime1 and startTime1 & am trying to use the following:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
Minutes difference = ((Minutes.minutesBetween(airTime1,startTime1)));
LocalTime remaining1 = formatter.parseLocalTime(difference);
```

Remaining 1 should then hold the time duration value between airTime1 & startTime1.  Remaining will then write to an image

```
Graphics g = image2.getGraphics();
g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(30f));
g.drawString((String.valueOf(remaining1)), 100, 100);
g.dispose();
```

I end up with an error that minutes cannot be converted to string.  What variable type do I need to be using in order to get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to store in remaining1?

Comment: The time duration between the airTime1 and startTime1

Comment: We could discuss this more in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110302/correct-format-for-hours-between-two-times-in-java[link]

Comment: I'm afraid I can't type in chatrooms until I have 20 rep

Comment: Haha thank you.  I guess it takes a while to update though as it's still showing the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110309/discussion-between-will-and-sebenalern).

Comment: I haven't yet figured this out, are you available today at all?

Comment: Yeah, I will take a look at it tonight. Sorry I have been busy lately, I just finished school for the year.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem you're running into is that a time duration is a distinct concept from an actual date-time. The lines

```
Minutes difference = ((Minutes.minutesBetween(airTime1,startTime1)));
LocalTime remaining1 = formatter.parseLocalTime(difference);
```

don't make sense because the idea of converting a duration to a date-time doesn't make sense. What is the date-time that represents, say, "3 minutes"? The closest thing I could imagine is a pair of date-times, one for the start and one for the end, but that's what you had already.

The Minutes representation (or possibly [the Hours representation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Hours.html#hoursBetween(org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,org.joda.time.ReadableInstant)), based on your stated use case) is actually what you want as is, I think you're just over-thinking it. No need to convert it further, just use it to build the string you want:

```
// Get difference, same as before
Minutes difference = ((Minutes.minutesBetween(airTime1,startTime1)));
// Create string representation of difference 
// (Minutes.toString() representation exists but is hard to read)
String diffStr = difference.getMinutes() / 60.0 + " hours" // for, e.g., "3.5 hours"

// Re-use your old graphics code with new string
Graphics g = image2.getGraphics();
g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(30f));
g.drawString(diffStr, 100, 100);
g.dispose();
```